# Pizza Challenge. Print bill for pizza order

Tags: python

I am completly stuck on the part where you have to print the total cost of the pizza and toppings. Ive tried string but still cant get it to work.
here is what i have to far:

```
print(" Welcome to Pizza Paradise! ")
print(" Our prices are")

print(" $6.95 for small")
print(" $8.49 for medium")
print(" $10.49 for large")
print(" $13.49 for XL")

pizza = str(input('Which size pizza do you want: S/M/L/XL?'))

while pizza != "S" and pizza != "M" and pizza!="L" and pizza!="XL"and pizza!="s"and pizza!="m"and      pizza!="l"and pizza!="xl":
    print(" That is not a valid answer")
    pizza = str(input("Which size pizza do you want: S/M/L/XL?"))
    print(pizza.upper())

print('''
Each topping is $1.45
''')

print("These are your choices")
print("Please type 11 when you are done")


print("1 - Olives")
print("2 - Mushrooms")
print("3 - Green Peppers")
print("4 - Hot peppers")
print("5 - Onions")
print("6 - Pineapple")
print("7 - Anchovies")
print("8 - Sausage")
print("9 - Pepperoni")
print("10 - Cheese")

print("11 - No more")

valid_choices = [str(x) for x in range(1, 11)]  # 1..10

while True:
    while True:
        toppings = input('Which topping would you like on your pizza: 1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9/10?')
        if toppings == "11" or toppings in valid_choices:
            break
        print("That is not a valid choice.")
    
    if toppings == "11":
        break
```

here are screen shots to clarify
[image]
[image]

Comment: The part where you have to print out the bill for the pizza and the topings

Comment: `print("6 - Pineapple")` is obviously invalid pizza topping.

Comment: just say you need some Homework to be programmed

Comment: "i'm stuck" is not a valid question here. [ask]

Comment: @Julien Why is `Pineapple` invalid? It is the best Pizza topping

Comment: HINT: all you need to do is *count* the number of *valid* topping choices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make some changes/add some variable, but this gets the job done.

```
print(" Welcome to Pizza Paradise! ")
print(" Our prices are")

print(" $6.95 for small")
print(" $8.49 for medium")
print(" $10.49 for large")
print(" $13.49 for XL")

pizza = str(input('Which size pizza do you want: S/M/L/XL?'))

while pizza != "S" and pizza != "M" and pizza != "L" and pizza != "XL" and pizza != "s" and pizza != "m" and pizza != "l" and pizza != "xl":
    print(" That is not a valid answer")
    pizza = str(input("Which size pizza do you want: S/M/L/XL?"))
    print(pizza.upper())

print('''
Each topping is $1.45
''')

print("These are your choices")
print("Please type 11 when you are done")

print("1 - Olives")
print("2 - Mushrooms")
print("3 - Green Peppers")
print("4 - Hot peppers")
print("5 - Onions")
print("6 - Pineapple")
print("7 - Anchovies")
print("8 - Sausage")
print("9 - Pepperoni")
print("10 - Cheese")
print("11 - No more")

valid_choices = [str(x) for x in range(1, 11)]  # 1..10

toppings_count = 0
pizza_cost = 0
toppings = input(
    'Which topping would you like on your pizza: 1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9/10?')
while toppings != "11" and toppings in valid_choices:
    toppings_count += 1
    toppings = input(
        'Which topping would you like on your pizza: 1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9/10?')

if pizza.upper() == "S":
    pizza_cost = 6.95
elif pizza.upper() == "M":
    pizza_cost = 8.49
elif pizza.upper() == "L":
    pizza_cost = 10.49
elif pizza.upper() == "XL":
    pizza_cost = 13.49

Total = (toppings_count * 1.45) + pizza_cost
print(Total)
```

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple errors in your code, so I changed the style. You can also do it this way it feels a bit more organized.

```
# pizza price calc
def price(tops_len,base_price):
    pizza_price=base_price+(1.45)*(tops_len)
    return pizza_price

def display_topping():
    toppings={'1':'Olives','2':'Mushrooms','3':'Cheese','4':'Pepperoni'}
    return toppings


def take_input():
    base=input("SELECT THE PIZZA YOU WANT. S-$2,M-$4,L-$6")
    if base=='S':
        base_price=2
    if base=='M':
        base_price=4
    if base=='L':
        base_price=6    
    toppings=display_topping()
    print(toppings)
    x=10
    tops=[]
    while x!=0:
        sel_tops=input("PLEASE SELECT THE TOPPINGS YOU WANT 1/2/3/4. TYPE 0 WHEN YOU ARE DONE")
        if sel_tops in toppings.keys() or sel_tops=='0':
            if sel_tops=='0':
                x=0
            else:
                tops.append(sel_tops)
        else:
            print('PLEASE PROVIDE A VALID INPUT')
    tops_len=len(tops)
    p=price(tops_len,base_price)
    print('your final price of the pizza is {}'.format(p))

take_input()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep a track of the pizza size, have a dictionary with prices for each size and then just keep a track of valid toppings. Here is how you can do it. Do check the marked statements with `#<---`

```
print(" Welcome to Pizza Paradise! ")
print(" Our prices are")

print(" $6.95 for small")
print(" $8.49 for medium")
print(" $10.49 for large")
print(" $13.49 for XL")

pizza = str(input('Which size pizza do you want: S/M/L/XL?'))

while pizza != "S" and pizza != "M" and pizza!="L" and pizza!="XL"and pizza!="s"and pizza!="m"and pizza!="l"and pizza!="xl":
    print(" That is not a valid answer")
    pizza = str(input("Which size pizza do you want: S/M/L/XL?"))
    print(pizza.upper())

psize = pizza.upper()          #<----

print('''
Each topping is $1.45
''')

print("These are your choices")
print("Please type 11 when you are done")


print("1 - Olives")
print("2 - Mushrooms")
print("3 - Green Peppers")
print("4 - Hot peppers")
print("5 - Onions")
print("6 - Pineapple")
print("7 - Anchovies")
print("8 - Sausage")
print("9 - Pepperoni")
print("10 - Cheese")

print("11 - No more")

valid_choices = [str(x) for x in range(1, 11)]  # 1..10

count_toppings = 0

while True:
    while True:
        toppings = input('Which topping would you like on your pizza: 1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9/10?')
        if toppings == "11" or toppings in valid_choices:
            count_toppings+=1                                        #<----
            break
        print("That is not a valid choice.")
    
    if toppings == "11":
        break
        
prices = {'S':6.95, 'M':8.49, 'L':10.49, 'XL':13.49}                 #<----
total_cost = prices.get(psize)+count_toppings*1.45                   #<----
print("One",psize,"Pizza with",count_toppings,"toppings is $",round(total_cost,3)) #<-----
```

```
Welcome to Pizza Paradise! 
 Our prices are
 $6.95 for small
 $8.49 for medium
 $10.49 for large
 $13.49 for XL
Which size pizza do you want: S/M/L/XL?XL

Each topping is $1.45

These are your choices
Please type 11 when you are done
1 - Olives
2 - Mushrooms
3 - Green Peppers
4 - Hot peppers
5 - Onions
6 - Pineapple
7 - Anchovies
8 - Sausage
9 - Pepperoni
10 - Cheese
11 - No more
Which topping would you like on your pizza: 1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9/10?6
Which topping would you like on your pizza: 1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9/10?5
Which topping would you like on your pizza: 1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9/10?4
Which topping would you like on your pizza: 1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9/10?3
Which topping would you like on your pizza: 1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9/10?2
Which topping would you like on your pizza: 1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9/10?11
One XL Pizza with 6 toppings is $ 22.19
```